# How can I simulate a device's display size and resolution on my monitior?

Tags: display, resolution

I'm creating a program for a raspberry pi touchscreen and I want to render the program on my computer monitor to the same size as the touchscreen. I want reduce the time making visual changes to the program and then needing to load and run the program on the device to confirm if the changes look good. To compare the program on the monitor and on the device and have it the same size in inches. Is that possible?

I have a monitor normally displaying at 1920 x 1080 with 93 pixels per inch (20.75 inch x 11.67 inch) and the touchscreen is displaying at 1024 x 600 with about 118 pixels per inch (10.1 touchscreen, so [ppi = D<sub>pixel</sub> / D<sub>inch</sub>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density#Calculation_of_monitor_PPI) = (1024<sup>2</sup> + 600<sup>2</sup>)<sup>-2</sup> / 10.1) = ~1186.83/10.1 = ~117.51).

I tried looking for a tool with the programming language I'm using (Java with JavaFX), but it only rendered the resolution within the monitor size. I also tried to figure out if I could change the monitor resolution to better size it to fit, but since the touchscreen's pixel density is higher, that doesn't seem feasible unless I made the pixel sizing in the application proportional to the ratio of the monitor and device ppi's.

Is this possible in a uncomplicated manner?

Edit - In case this comes up, there are no display ports for the touchscreen because it plugs directly into the board. Trying to hook up the touchscreen directly to the computer as another monitor seems too complicated.

Comment: Would a [VM with Raspbian](https://raspberrytips.com/run-raspberry-in-virtual-machine/) (if that is what you're using) work?

Comment: If you have an old CRT laying around, you may be able send an image of arbitrary size and number of pixels to it.  But modern flatscreens have a definite number of pixels in their grids.

Comment: Our sister site may have some Answers to this question already : https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @CaldeiraG, I'm not sure if that can help with recreating the display with the same dimensions in inches, but I'll see if I could tweak the display settings.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage, I don't have any CRTs unfortunately, but I will check out raspberrypi.stackexchage.com and either share any answers I find or post a question there too.